# How to use write access using iterators and armadillo sparse matrices?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

I have to replace some columns in a sparse matrix with columns from another sparse matrix that has the same nonzero elements, just different values, based on a condition.

I am struggling with write access using iterators in Armadillo. The docs say that using sp_mat::col_iterator provides read/write access, however, when I try to write a value `*it = B.col(...)` I get an error message `error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘arma::SpValProxy<arma::SpMat<double> >’ and ‘arma::SpSubview_col<double>’)`. Do I have a syntax mistake or am I understanding the concept of "write access" wrong?

```
  arma::sp_mat A = arma::sprandu(100, 100, 0.01);
  arma::sp_mat B(A);
  B *= 2;
  arma::vec condition = arma::randi<arma::vec>(100, arma::distr_param(0, 1));
  
  arma::sp_mat::col_iterator it = A.begin();
  arma::sp_mat::col_iterator it_end = A.end();
  for(; it != it_end; ++it){
    if (condition(it.col())==1){
      *it = B.col(it.col());
    }
  }
```

My solution at the moment is to write a function collecting the indices & values from the respective matrix and then use batch initialization, similar to [Access and modify the non zero elements of sparse matrix of class arma::sp_mat using Rcpp code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222092/access-and-modify-the-non-zero-elements-of-sparse-matrix-of-class-armasp-mat-u). Nevertheless I would still like to learn about read/write access and iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the (generally excellent) [Armadillo documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html), I think you are up a against a design issue.  Quoting

> Caveats:
>
> - to modify the non-zero elements in a safer manner, use .transform() or .for_each() instead of iterators;
> - writing a zero value into a sparse matrix through an iterator will invalidate all current iterators associated with the sparse matrix
>   row iterators for sparse matrices are only useful with Armadillo 8.500 and later versions; in earlier versions they are inefficient

Comment: That answers my question, thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to have been of help, and belated welcome to StackOverflow. You can "accept" the answer by clicking on the tick-mark only you as the question asker see, and you "upvote" it by clicking on the up-triangle.  Both are common and recommended.